# How can we make rsync include top level files?

Tags: rsync

I want to include all top level files (`file1.txt`, `file2`) and only anything under `/top/dir1/`. How can I achieve it?

I have tried the following but they don't work

```
$ tree
.
└── from
    ├── file1.txt
    ├── file2
    └── top
        ├── dir1
        │   └── file3.txt
        └── dir2
            └── file4.txt
```

one attempt, missing top level files

```
$ rsync --dry-run \
>       --include='top/' \
>       --include='top/dir1/' \
>       --include='top/dir1/***' \
>       --exclude='top/*' \
>       --exclude="*" \
>       -av from/* .
building file list ... done
top/
top/dir1/
top/dir1/file3.txt
```

other attempt to include top level files but it's not excluding dir2

```
$ rsync --dry-run \
>       --include="*" \
>       --include='top/' \
>       --include='top/dir1/' \
>       --include='top/dir1/***' \
>       --exclude='top/*' \
>       --exclude="*" \
>       -av from/* .
building file list ... done
file1.txt
file2
top/
top/dir1/
top/dir1/file3.txt
top/dir2/
top/dir2/file4.txt
```

Comment: Don't ask the same question in multiple places :(

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using another command to do the filtering, you could use a couple of GNU `find` commands:

```
(cd from; find . -mindepth 1 -type f -print0; find ./top/dir1 -print0;) |
  rsync -av --from0 --files-from=- from/ to
```

From [`man rsync`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/rsync.1.html):

```
    --files-from=FILE       read list of source-file names from FILE
-0, --from0                 all *from/filter files are delimited by 0s
```

`rsync` can accept a list of files to sync from another file (or standard input `-`), but the paths have to be relative (or we must use `--no-R` to allow absolute paths). Hence, first `cd` to the source directory, then run `find` with appropriate options:

- `-mindepth 1` to restrict only to the specified directories, without recursing to subdirectories
- `-type f` to list only regular files
- `-print0` to delimit the output using ASCII NUL characters (`\0`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to include EVERYTHING at the top level, and only dir1 under top.

```
rsync --dry-run \                                      
   --include='top/dir1/***' \
   --exclude='top/*' \
   -av from/ .
```